# How to add additional constraints to Concorde TSP solver

Tags: traveling-salesman, np-hard

I am trying to solve a modified version of the Traveling Salesmen Problem.  This is a modification of the basic TSP so that all nodes have a color property and the optimal path cannot Touch more than four nodes of the same color sequentially.  This will be run in a connected graph of no more than 100 nodes.  I am trying to run this using Concorde.

Does anyone know how to add the color constraint to a Concorde run?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Concorde is set up to add arbitrary constraints. The solver is highly customized for the classical TSP and can't accommodate new constraints like that. The only way to do it would be if you can figure out a way to convert your problem into a classical TSP by changing the data only (not the constraints), i.e., by coming up with some trick to set the cost matrix so that optimal solutions always satisfy the color constraint, but I can't see a way to do that, off hand.